# Call an fragment method from a fragment

Tags: android

Current my fragment A opens a new dialog fragment B. `Is there any way to call method from a fragment A method from a dialog fragment B?`

Comment: Could you pass a reference to Fragment A to Fragment B when you initialize it? Then call it by that reference in Fragment B?

Comment: how can i pass method through reference

Comment: Pass the whole Fragment, then in Frag B call `myReference.myMethod()`.

Comment: `public CustomAlertBoxFragment(Activity a, MyFragClass frag) { this.c = a; this.frag = frag;}` Then later you'd call `this.frag.yourMethod();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to android web site, you shouldn't call a fragment from another fragment, instead you should let activity to handle switching fragments.

To do that,

You can create an interface and implement it in activity,

```
public interface MyListener{
    public void switchFragment(Fragment f);
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyListener{

    @Override
    public void switchFragement(Fragment f){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction
                 .replace(R.id.container, f)
                 .commit();
    }
}
```

and in fragment classes,

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    private MyListener listener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (MyListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement MyListener");
        }
    }

   @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }

}
```

and simply use

```
listener.switchFragment(fragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to one of 2 things:

- Wire a reference to each Fragment in your Activity
- Use an Enterprise Service Bus (Otto is an open-source option) to communicate directly between Fragments

There is NO way to talk direct Fragment to Fragment in the standard framework.  You must manually create this linkage.

Comment: how to Wire a reference to each Fragment in my Activity